# Add custom registry keys using installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, setup-project, solidworks

I wrote a Addin for Solidworks (a .dll). In order for Solidworks to find it there is an additional registry key needed that I set in the `ComRegistryFunction`.
When I compile it and register the .dll using `regasm.exe \tlb`, everything works as intended.

Now I want to distribute the Addin, and I was looking into setup projects to have everything nicely packaged. I googled a lot but frankly, it's quite hard to find reliable information on this topic. Here is what I did:

- Add my dll as "primary output" to the setup project
- For this file, set Register to 'vsdrpCOM'

However, the setup does not set the custom registry keys (It appears it does not run the ComRegisterFunction of my class).

I was able to get it to work by *manually* adding these registry keys to the Registry tab of the Setup project. But that means I have to manually enter the class' GUID, as well as the description and title even though all of this is specified in the class already. I know I will forget to change one or the other at some point in the future.

How can I make the installer automatically pull these register keys and set them?

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and .Net v4.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the Windows Installer function does not call any register function code.

The vsdrpCOM setting should do most of the registration, and it should extract at build time into the Class table of the MSI file and some in the Registry table - you can check by opening the MSI file in Orca and seeing what was extracted. You didn't say exactly what was missing, given that there are class and interface registry entries. The other confusion may be whether your MSI file is targeted at 32-bit or 64-bit and where you expect the registry entries to be created (classes\root vs software\classes and native 64-bit vs WoW6432). Also note that Windows Installer takes the per user "Just me" setting literally, so you will per user COM registration, not per system.

This might help, old but these projects haven't changed over the years:

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/visual-studio/build-and-deploy-a-net-com-assembly/

So check the architecture and Everyone/Just me settings, and look at those MSI tables to see what's there.

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford it time-wise I'd strongly suggest switching from VS setup project to [wix](http://wixtoolset.org/). It has a steep learning curve but is miles ahead on functionality and customizability. To solve your issue with wix you'd use [heat](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/heat.html) utility that comes as part of the toolset and generates xml config that contains com registration based on your dll. I do believe it will include custom registrations, but just in case check this first.

On the other hand if you do not plan in the future to make installers of any significant complexity I think you can make a custom action for VS setup project and call regasm manually with Process.Start(). Or better yet put your custom registrations in the custom action itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you elaborate on how to add registration to the custom action?

Comment: You just take the code from your ComRegistryFunction and put it in the custom action. If you are asking how to add custom action itself - it's relatively trivial task, there are a lot of tutorials online. Google "add custom action for visual studio setup project C#"